# Forcing flag to be unique

Tags: 7, flags

In Drupal 7, using [Flags](http://drupal.org/project/flag) (and possibly [Rules](http://drupal.org/project/rules) or another contrib module) how can I force a flag to be unique for a specific content type.  I do not want to force users to manually 'unflag' content before 'flagging' a new node.  I would like reviously flagged nodes to be automatically unflagged once a new flag has been set.

The goal is to allow users to select a 'default node' by use of flags.  Only one default node should be allowed.

How can I force and automate flag uniqueness?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Drupal [Rules](http://drupal.org/project/rules) has a [Trim-A-Flag](http://drupal.org/node/407070) action that lets you set a 'queue' size, or a 'max' number of flags allowed.  If you set the queue to 1, you can force a flag to be unique, and have it automatically update when a new entity is flagged.

Screenshot below.

[image: Drupal Rules Trim-a-Flag settings]

Answer (score 1):

You could use `hook_flag($action, $flag, $content_id, $account)` to do this. In this hook, check for content type, and then unflag all unneeded nodes.